# Regex Expression To Accept Spaces in String

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have an existing regex expression: `"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]"` for a parameter. I need to add to it so that I can allow spaces in a string expression when I validate.

How would I add to this expression to allow spaces? Would it be: `"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_- ]"`?

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex already allows spaces. It "disallows" listed sequences: `^` means negation when first in class.

Comment: Does `"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]"` work for you?

Comment: Minor note (very minor): "regex expression" is equivalent to "**reg**ular **ex**pression expression". Like saying "PIN number" or "ATM machine"... This message was brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.